# New to Django - get list of users with the most posts

Tags: django

First post and new to python and django.

I am trying to add context to a ListView so that I can display a list of top 5 most commented posts and also a list of top 5 most active users (users with most posts).  I have got the first list working however can't work out the second list.  Using the values method (i think it's a method) i've managed to query the database and get back a dictionary of user_id and posts count.  My problem is that I want to display the username rather than the user_id.  For some reason this query results in a dictionary rather than the full object.  I've posted the code from views.py below.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
queryset = Article.objects.filter(published=True)
template_name = 'articles/index.html' #address of non default template
context_object_name = 'articles' #variable name passed to template
ordering = ['-pub_date']

#get query results for popular posts and most active users side bar
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['most_commented'] = Article.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).order_by('-comment_count')[:5]
      context['most_active'] = Article.objects.all().values('author').annotate(active=Count('author')).order_by('-active')[:5]
      return context
```

Thank you for your help!

Nick

Comment: Can you provide the `Article` model? What is `author`? A `ForeignKey` to *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, `values` is a method that returns `dict`s. If you want the full object, there's no need to use values here:

```
context['most_active'] = Article.objects.all().annotate(active=Count('author')).order_by('-active')[:5]
```

You can then iterate through `most_active` in the template and access the username directly.

If you did want to use `values`, just pass the fields you want returned in the dict:

```
context['most_active'] = Article.objects.all().values('author__username').annotate(active=Count('author')).order_by('-active')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it too complicated. You can annotate the `User` to obtain the most `User`s with the most published articles:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Article.objects.filter(published=True)
    template_name = 'articles/index.html' #address of non default template
    context_object_name = 'articles' #variable name passed to template
    ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['most_commented'] = Article.objects.annotate(
          comment_count=Count('comments')
      ).order_by('-comment_count')[:5]
      context['most_active'] = User.objects.annotate(
          narticles=Count('article')
      ).order_by('-narticles')[:5]
      return context
```